# Having problems displaying image within JButton

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton

http://tinypic.com/r/25rcxa1/8

Hello everyone. I' am having trouble having my picture being viewable within the JButton. Why isn't this compiling? I have placed image in src folder as you can see from the picture of my dual monitor setup,which shows folder hierarchy and eclipse IDE.

Comment: please include source coder here also for easier viewing

Comment: Yes, where's your source code? This question as it stands devolves to: `"please tell me why the code I'm not showing you is not working"`, a question which is **very** hard for mortals to answer. Note that code should not be displayed as an image but as text.

Comment: sorry all but i need reputation 10 to show images it says.

Comment: Again, please don't post code as an image. Understand that many of us have firewalls that prevent our going to links. Post your code text as part of your question. You will want to go through the [tour] and the [help] section before asking questions. If you don't understand this comment and need additional explanation, please let us know just what about this request confuses you.

Comment: Having seen the image, I think it helps to see how the files are laid out in the filesystem

Answer (score 1):

Actually the code compiles, and you have a runtime exception. That's because you pass `"../geek.jpg"` to the `ImageIcon` constructor, and that's not how resource resolution [works](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)).

You should use `"/geek.jpg"` instead, provided the image will also be packaged along with your app (check your Eclipse deployment/packaging configuration)